# Повторная запись пользователя в таблицу

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

У меня есть таблица от postgreSQL, я пытаюсь проверять айди каждого пользователя и если таблица такой находит, то она не записывает пользователя, но мой код не работает и повторно записывает данные, хотя если я попробую найти пользователя с определенным айди в таблице в pgadmin4, то быстро нахожу, в чем проблема?
Код:

```
for guild in bot.guilds:
    for member in guild.members:
        print('#####')
        print(member.id)
        print(cursor.execute(f'SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}'))
        print('#####')
        if cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}') is None:
            cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users (id,name,cash,mes,mesnum,mute,marry,marryname,voicetime,voiceprivat,voiceevent,textevent,voicetech,texttech,mutenum,unmutenum) VALUES ({member.id},'{member}',{5},{0},{0},{0},{0},' ',{0},{0},{0},{0},{0},{0},{0},{0})")
            connection.commit()
```

Таблица:

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id BIGINT,
    name TEXT,
    cash BIGINT,
    mes BIGINT,
    mesnum BIGINT,
    mute BIGINT,
    marry BIGINT,
    marryname TEXT,
    voicetime BIGINT,
    voiceprivat BIGINT,
    voiceevent BIGINT,
    textevent BIGINT,
    voicetech BIGINT,
    texttech BIGINT,
    mutenum BIGINT,
    unmutenum BIGINT
    )""")
```

С sqlite3 все отлично выходило, но здесь возникают проблемы.

Comment: Не надо изобретать велосипед. Уникальный индекс.

Comment: Метод `cursor.execute` всегда возвращает `None`. Чтобы получить результат, нужно использовать `fetch`

Comment: @Akina если я не буду записывать айди, то не смогу нормально взаимодействовать с пользователем, ведь это дискорд бот.

Comment: @Evrik я пытался использовать fetchone, но выдает ошибку, что не допустимо к типу None.

Comment: попробуйте прочитать значение `cursor.rowcount`

Comment: @Evrik да, понял ошибку, нужно переменной присваивать, очень неудобно :( sqlite3 мог с fetchone сразу находить.

Comment: @CookieEater так сделайте себе для удобства функции обертки над стандартным драйвером работы с БД, например объедините в них execute с fetch. А akina вам все верно говорил, делаете колонку id уникальной (первичным ключом или уникальным индексом) и пишите запрос `insert into ... values ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` и все, он вставит пользователя только если такого id еще нет, а если он есть (нарушается уникальный ключ) то ничего делать не будет. И проверять ничего не надо.

Comment: @Mike благодарю за идею, айди к сожалению не я создаю, я пишу дискорд бота, там нужны для удобства айди пользователя в самом дискорде.

Comment: ну это не важно, кто id создает. все равно вторую запись при наличии уникальности записать не удастся  :)